# System.TimeoutException Error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

We changed our Orchestration from using HTTP adapter to Wcf-WebHttp Adapter to call the REST service. In the Orchestration previously we used

```
Message(HTTP.RequestTimeout) = 3600;
```

Now with Wcf-WebHttp adapter which timeout do I need to use. Because there are WCF.CloseTimeout, WCF.LeaseTimeout, WCF.OpenTimeout,WCF.SendTimeout.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set WCF.OpenTimeout, WCF.SendTimeout, and WCF.CloseTimeout.

Per the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh924831(v=VS.110).aspx):

- SendTimeout governs the whole request/response.
- OpenTimeout governs the time to make the open the channel
- CloseTimeout governs the time to close the channel.

Also be aware that there is a master MSDTC timeout in Machine.config that's defaulted to 10 minutes.  That shouldn't be an issue here, but if you need to modify it here's the information: http://blog.brandt-lassen.dk/2012/11/overriding-default-10-minutes.html

Comment: All three TimeOuts needs to be given or Just SendTimeout is enough? Since it governs the request/Response..

Comment: can all these three timeouts be over 10 minutes. Or it needs to be 10 minutes because master MSDTC timeout in Machine.config that's defaulted to 10 minutes

Comment: I tried to give timeout `Message(WCF.OpenTimeout)= "01:00:00";
Message(WCF.CloseTimeout)= "01:00:00";
Message(WCF.SendTimeout)= "01:00:00";` Now it gives me below error

Comment: `Error details: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to .... This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down).`

Comment: `See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389070/configure-wcf-receive-location-in-biztalk